# How set Foreground with binding on materialdesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, foreground, material-design-in-xaml

I can't set Foreground of a columncell with binding, if I use that syntax in xaml:

```
<materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"/>
```

On windows load in the output terminal I see that:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Foreground; DataItem=null; target element is 'MaterialDataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=29149718); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')

If I put the direct color for example:

```
<materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Foreground="Red"/>
```

The Datagrid Cell render foreground correctly, did anyone have some suggestion?

Best Regards

Franco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

I have to work with ElementStyle property:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I Hope this is usefull to someone else.

Regards

Franco